# UICollectionViewController that looks like UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface

I want to make a controller that will looks like UICollectionView in one case and UITableView in other case. In other words, this controller should use one data but display it in different ways. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You could probably manage making a collection view look like a table view, but that would be a lot of work. I think a simpler approach would be to have two view controllers, one for the table and one for the collection. Use a data source that can be shared between the controllers. For example, you could have your data in an array in your AppDelegate that is reachable by both.

Comment: can you share the screenshots of the screen how you want your collectionView look like in the two different styles. It is hard to give any suggestion without knowing the ultimate goal. We need to know at least how many subviews will the cell have in the two different configurations.  @RussellAustin is correct that it will be a lot of work if there are many subviews in the cell.